# Is there a way to pass multiple (and different) parameters to an Apex Controller class from JS in Lightning Web Components (LWC)?

Tags: apex, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I'm currently stuck at a problem and was hoping someone here could help me. I also certainly hope this is the right place to ask it.

I'm trying to create a custom Invoice record with its corresponding Invoice Line records upon firing an event. I already have some logic in place to gather ID of selected rows in the JS.

I've gone so far as to be able to create the Invoice record (using LDS) and the Invoice Line records (using Apex), but can't seem to pass the Invoice ID for the Invoice Line records. I know I'm able to create the records because it works when I tested this with a hardcoded Invoice ID.

Would it be possible to pass multiple parameters of List and String to an Apex method in LWC?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

**JS**

```
    selectedRowsEvent(event) {
    
    // Some codes here...
    
    this.selectedRecords = Array.from(conIds);
    }
    
    
    handleSave() {
    invId;
    const fields = {};
    fields[INVOICE_ACCOUNTMD_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.wiredRecord.data.fields.AccountId__c.value;
    fields[INVOICE_OPPLKP_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.wiredRecord.data.fields.Id.value;
    const recordInput = { apiName: INVOICE_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };
   
    // CREATE THE INVOICE RECORD
    createRecord(recordInput)
        .then(invoice => {
            this.message = invoice;
            this.error = undefined;  
            if(this.message !== undefined) {
                this.invId = invoice.Id;   
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Invoice created',
                        variant: 'success',
                    }),
                );
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(invoice));
            console.log("invoice", this.message);

            // CREATE THE INVOICE LINE RECORDS
            createInvLines({ lstConIds : this.selectedRecords, invoiceId : this.invId})
            .then(result => {
                this.message = result;
                this.error = undefined;
                if(this.message !== undefined) {
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Success',
                            message: 'Invoice Line records created',
                            variant: 'success',
                        }),
                    );
                }
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log("invoice line", this.message);
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.message = undefined;
            this.error = error;
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'We encountered an error creating the record(s).',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error',
                }),
            );
            console.log("error", JSON.stringify(this.error));
        }); 
    }
```

**Controller**

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static void createInvLines(list<Id> lstConIds, string invoiceId){
        if(lstConIds.size() > 0){
            List<OpportunityLine__c> oppLst = new List<OpportunityLine__c>([SELECT Id, Description__c FROM OpportunityLine__c WHERE Id = :lstConIds]);
            try {
                List<InvoiceLine__c> lstInvLinesToInsert = new List<InvoiceLine__c>();
                for(OpportunityLine__c idCon : oppLst) {
                    lstInvLinesToInsert.add(new InvoiceLine__c(**InvoiceId__c = invoiceId**, Description__c = idCon.Description__c));
                }
                if(!lstInvLinesToInsert.isEmpty()) {
                    insert lstInvLinesToInsert;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED:** Included a screenshot of the Browser Console debugging below. I've also posted the complete handleSave() functionality from the JS. Please take a look.

[image: Network Console Logs]

Comment: This should work, please post the error(s) you are getting if any.
The full JS Controller would be much appreciated.

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Please make sure that there is a value for `this.invId`. You want to go in debugging what is sent to the server, open the browser console `Network tab` before this call is made, and check the request parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking at but I've posted the debugging results and it does look like the Invoice Id is empty. Here is a complete message for the error: "Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Invoice]: [Invoice]". I've included more info on my JS as well. Please feel free to take a look.

Comment: It looks like the Id property of the invoice is being returned with the lowercase label in the result object. Try invoice.id, javascript is cap sensitive

Comment: Thanks for all the help, you guys. It was indeed a case sensitivity issue. Using the browser as a debugging tool was pretty helpful too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, invoice id is coming as undefined because of case sensitive issue. Can you try to change the line `this.invId = invoice.Id;` to `this.invId = invoice.id;`

Let me know if it is not working...

Comment: Brilliant. I would have never thought it was because of a case sensitive issue.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome sid! I think it is working now.